# ConstraintLayout shows height but is actually 0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` within a layout file and when I set the `height` of the `ConstraintLayout` to be **0dp** and set additional constraints, I can see that the layout is at the size of what I want ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abs1y.png)), however, when I put another `View` within the layout (in this case a `MapView`), it does not resize to its `parent`'s **height** ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOu4K.png))! This is my whole XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dialogContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/closeDialogButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_close_workorder"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semibold"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/textTint"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gotham_medium"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialogInfo" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialogTitle">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_description" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_light"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryDark"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/dividerColor"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout6">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_materials" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/materialsText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_light"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryDark"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/dividerColor"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout7">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_contact" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_light"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryDark"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noMapInstruction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Geen kaart beschikbaar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout9" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout9">

        <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/locationMap"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="11"
            mapbox:mapbox_renderTextureMode="true"
            mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/fadedWhite"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout9">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locationText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_light"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryDark"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_location" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/openWorkOrder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:src="@drawable/button_open_workorder"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me and help me get the full `ConstraintLayout`'s height? [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJMFq.png) is what I'm trying to achieve, but without the info of the middle view (the contact icon). So basically, the `MapView` should be displayed **behind** the location text.

Comment: That whole the layout is wrong! What's the sense of using nested ConstraintLayout if the main purpose of them is to keep the layout as flatten as possible and avoid nested components?

Take a look at https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html to get a better idea what ConstraintLayout is intended for.

Answer (score 1):

Those constraints:

```
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

Ignores the width set in layout_width and join the left of this view with the left of the parent, and the right to the right, the result will be a match_parent width.

Similar, you can do Top_topTopOf="parent" and Bottom_toBottomOf="parent" but since you have more views on screen if you want to place then linearly you can use the Top_toBottomOf="@id/other"

Comment: I am doing this for the ConstraintLayout, right? And then assigning 'parent' to the top and bottom constraints of the MapView.

Comment: Yes but look the textview above it, it already has bottom_tobottom of parent and top at the same start of the constraint layout, also, you are too overusing views in the xml, you will have to check mostly things, if you can post a print of what you want and what is happening.

Comment: You are adding many views on top of each other, show us what you really wnat

Comment: So how to you get the width of the constraint layout then if its zero?

Comment: By constrainting the view to leftToLeft and rightToLeft it assumes the size of constraints

Answer (score 0):

Change `0dp` with `wrap_content` for both the `MapView` and its container. And possibly for other layouts as well.

Also, I see you're using a lot of `ConstraintLayout`s. For instance the dividers (`divider1` and `divider2`) are `ConstraintLayout` but could simply be `View`s, which would improve performance.